# Stabilizer in infinite Galois Group

Tags: abstract-algebra, profinite-groups

I have following question:
Let finite field and $ G =  \varprojlim Gal(\bar{\mathbb{F}_p}|\mathbb{F}_p)$ 
equiped with canonical profinite topology indeced by inverse system
$ (\phi _{i,j}, Gal(\mathbb{F}_{p^i},\mathbb{F}_p)$.
My question is how to see that for every $ a \in 
\bar{\mathbb{F}_p}$ every $Stab_G(a) = \{g \in G | g(a) =a \}$ is 
open in G.

My idea:

According to finite Galois theory $a^G$ is finite, more
precisely thats is composed of roots of the minimal polynom of a. Because 
the roots are algebraic we can find a finite field extension $ \mathbb{F}_{p^i}$
which includes all roots. Futhermore $Stab_G(a)_{\mathbb{F}_{p^i}} := 
\{g \in Gal(\mathbb{F}_{p^i},\mathbb{F}_p) | g(a) =a \}$
is open in $ Gal(\mathbb{F}_{p^i},\mathbb{F}_p) $ since it has the discrete topology.
So so the preimage of $Stab_G(a)_{\mathbb{F}_{p^i}}$ unter
the projection map $\phi_i: Gal(\bar{\mathbb{F}_p}|\mathbb{F}_p) 
\to Gal(\mathbb{F}_{p^i},\mathbb{F}_p)$ is open. So if it would hold that 
$Stab_G(a) = \phi^{-1}Stab_G(a)_{\mathbb{F}_{p^i}}$ the proof whould be
finished. But is this equality correct?

Answer (score 0):

If we have that $ \mathbb F_p(a) $ is the finite field of cardinality $ p^n $ for some $ n $, we have that

$$ \textrm{Stab}_G(a) = \left( \prod_{2 \leq i < n} \textrm{Gal}(\mathbb F_{p^i}/\mathbb F_p) \times \{ \textrm{id} \} \times \prod_{i >  n} \textrm{Gal}(\mathbb F_{p^i}/\mathbb F_p) \right) \cap G $$

which is open since $ G $, as an inverse limit, inherits the subspace topology from the product; and the factors are discrete groups.